# Whenever i click on my right left button images are going downward

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a project in which Firstly i import card component using bootstrap and put some images there. Give them a center tag. In script.js I give button to function like whenever i click on right button it switch to next and vice verse. But when ever i amclicking on any button images are going downward instead of staying up there in a fixed position. Problem is that whenever i click the images it goes downward and again downward.

https://codepen.io/mohit-04/pen/abWPwPq

**When you click the button images go down and if again then even more down I want to keep up in centre between the button**

```js
// taking ids
const button = document.querySelectorAll("[data-carousel-button]");

// looping though next and prev button means
// ** LOGIC **

// storing all the images in array and then if we click the
// left arrow then it will go to -1 and if right then +1
//through this it will navigate through each images using index of images
button.forEach((button) => {
  // function which check which button is gonna be clicked
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const offset = button.dataset.carouselButton === "next" ? 1 : -1;
    // to navigate closest parent element making a loop in ul tag to navigate each li
    const slides = button
      .closest("[data-carousel]")
      .querySelector("[data-slides]");

    // just checking which slide means li has data active tag
    const activeSlide = slides.querySelector("[data-active]");
    // extracting all the li in array
    // getting the active slide and + offset means what we have to do means either +1 or -1
    let newIndex = [...slides.children].indexOf(activeSlide) + offset;

    // if it comes to last element and again user click left then it automatically goes to last element
    if (newIndex < 0) newIndex = slides.children.length - 1;
    if (newIndex >= slides.children.length) newIndex = 0;

    // adding .active to that slide and removeing data-active to the previous one
    slides.children[newIndex].dataset.active = true;
    delete activeSlide.dataset.active;
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url("a.avif");

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  /* position: absolute; */
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide > img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.carousel > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.slide[data-active] {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 4rem;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.carousel-button:hover,
.carousel-button:focus {
  color: purple;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.carousel-button:focus {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.carousel-button.prev {
  left: 24rem;
}

.carousel-button.next {
  right: 24rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="carousel" data-carousel>
        <button
          class="carousel-button next"
          data-carousel-button="next"
          data-carousel-button
        >
          &#8669;
        </button>
        <button
          class="carousel-button prev"
          data-carousel-button="prev"
          data-carousel-button
        >
          &#8668;
        </button>

        <ul data-slides>
          <li class="slide" data-active>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
              <img
                class="card-img-top"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1644982647531-daff2c7383f3?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=60&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="slide">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
              <img
                class="card-img-top"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653491888857-6cb8c8f0264c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxOHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="slide">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
              <img
                class="card-img-top"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625215081436-85323ed5042c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyNHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="slide">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
              <img
                class="card-img-top"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653597859079-bc6d0e9101de?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzNHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="slide">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
              <img
                class="card-img-top"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653604212161-b50f445f7987?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0M3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60"
                alt="Card image cap"
              />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://codepen.io/sparxia/pen/ZErvgKM I just added `display: flex` to the unordered list and restored the absolute positioning on each slide.

Comment: Do not use `<center>` tags. They are deprecated. Use flexbox centering method.

Comment: yes what you did. can you explain me ?

Comment: I explained.  _I just added `display: flex` to the unordered list and restored the absolute positioning on each slide._

Comment: can you tell me one more thing that in the last card component you can see that it is coming bigger rather than previous usual ones. how can i adjust the last card component to with the same size as previous

Comment: That depends on the image size. Wrap the image inside a container and set the width to it so that all the card images are of the same height and width.